# Header Location is not working

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I have searched for a while now, and it seems that I can't find a solution to my problem. I'm hoping that you guys can help me out.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    if(isset($_POST['searchstring'])){

        include ("connect.php");
        $queried = $_POST['searchstring'];

        $queried = trim($queried);

        $patterns = array("/\s+/", "/\s([?.!])/");
        $replacer = array("+","$1");

        $queried = preg_replace( $patterns, $replacer, $queried );

        header("Location: index.php?page=search&q=".$queried."");
    }
    else {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    exit();
?>
```

I have even tried to only use following code:

```
<?php header('Location: index.php'); ?>
```

That's not working either. It's pretty wierd, because I have used header location a million times. It works 100% fine on localhost, but on the server it fails - it just shows a blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems working good.. Can you try with real address for instance ? `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` ?

Comment: not 100% sure but ob_start prevents anything from being sent, including headers.

Comment: @Patrick, no. The output buffer simply prevents any output **except** headers. [function.ob-start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I have tried that as well. It doesn't seem to work either. It worked for you?

Comment: Same problem occurred to me also.On that case linux servers doesnt supported to me. I used `window.location.href` js code.

Comment: @Morten Yeah, i just gave with temporary values, and it works good

Comment: Have you checked for an error? Put `print_r(error_get_last());` before the exit() but after the header. It should state if PHP experienced a problem sending the header.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins it says: Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/6/b/d/domain.dk/httpd.www/SearchData.php:1) [file] => /customers/6/b/d/domain.dk/httpd.www/SearchData.php [line] => 15 )

Comment: Have you redirect to any page? Or it will stay as it?

Comment: @KhushangBhavnagarwala - it just shows a blank page.

Comment: Means it is redirect to the index.php page. M I Right?

Comment: So, line 15 is the `header("Location: index.php?page=search&q=".$queried."");`line.

Which implies that it is ignoring that line and then dying when it tries to execute the second header command. Try putting die('Attempted header and no result'); after that first header - that'll let you know exactly what the problem is. Providing that index.php file actually exists on the server I can't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins i've tried that now, and there is no error message besides "Attempted header and no result". index.php does indeed exist.

Comment: @Morten OK - it's simply not executing the header as you have defined. I would say that it's possible your host is running a SAPI that doesn't support them. Get in touch with their tech support.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - I just talked to them, and they support it. This is really, really wierd. Well, thank you guys for trying. I have to see what I can do now then. The code is correct, the host supports it - what is wrong... hmm..

Comment: @Morten - One minor point, you don't need the `.""` at the end of the header line, it's happy to end on just the variable. You might want to var_dump that variable and make sure it's a string - anything else might cause issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found the error. Apparently I had somehow saved my document with BOM, which made the code somehow invalid.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. use the full url instead of index.php.
2. Try with url like [http://example.com/index.php]